# Install virtualbox 4.1 - doesn't know about extension packs

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-9.10

I'm trying to get virtualbox set up in my Ubuntu 9.10 install so that i can use the windows images eg from this page:

https://github.com/xdissent/ievms

I have VirtualBox OSE installed already. The link i listed above has a shell script that is downloaded and run with curl, and this shell script falls over at this step:

```
$ VBoxManage list extpacks
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-ose-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
Sun VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 3.1.6_OSE
(C) 2005-2010 Sun Microsystems, Inc.
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage list [--long|-l] vms|runningvms|ostypes|hostdvds|hostfloppies|
                            bridgedifs|hostonlyifs|dhcpservers|hostinfo|
                            hostcpuids|hddbackends|hdds|dvds|floppies|
                            usbhost|usbfilters|systemproperties


Syntax error: Unknown subcommand "extpacks".
```

I tried `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose-dkms` and got `virtualbox-ose-dkms is already the newest version`.  I've got no idea what "the appropriate headers, most likely linux-headers-generic" might refer to.

Any ideas anyone?  thanks, max
PS Sorry if you think this belongs in an ubuntu forum...

Comment: Does ```lsmod | grep vbox``` show anything?

Comment: Forget the prepackaged OSE and install Virtualbox downloaded from the virtualbox.org site. The package repository contains old Guest Additions, somewhat 3.2 which will conflict with your Virtualbox 4.1.